# Google API revoke all permissions from developer's console?

Tags: google-api

I'm wondering if I can somehow remove all permissions granted by users for my application? I need them to re-grant permissions, but I'd like to avoid forcing the approval so they only have to do this once.

Just one question in addition to this, will that (if there's a way to do this) also remove all drive files permissions granted?